# RabbitMQ Management : webmachine error: path="/api/overview"

Tags: rabbitmq

After I login to rabbitmq, I get the following error :

Got response code 500 with body
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an error while processing this request:

```
{error,{error,{badmatch,{error,nxdomain}},
          [{rabbit_nodes,cluster_name_default,0},
           {rabbit_nodes,cluster_name,0},
           {rabbit_mgmt_wm_overview,to_json,2},
           {webmachine_resource,resource_call,3},
           {webmachine_resource,do,3},
           {webmachine_decision_core,resource_call,1},
           {webmachine_decision_core,decision,1},
           {webmachine_decision_core,handle_request,2}]}}
```

I see the following error in the log file in /var/log/rabbitmq :

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 31-Oct-2014::06:20:40 ===
webmachine error: path="/api/overview"
{error,{error,{badmatch,{error,nxdomain}},
          [{rabbit_nodes,cluster_name_default,0},
           {rabbit_nodes,cluster_name,0},
           {rabbit_mgmt_wm_overview,to_json,2},
           {webmachine_resource,resource_call,3},
           {webmachine_resource,do,3},
           {webmachine_decision_core,resource_call,1},
           {webmachine_decision_core,decision,1},
           {webmachine_decision_core,handle_request,2}]}}
```

The workers are able to connect to the broker and are receiving the messages, also the new relic plugin for rabbitmq seems to be working fine. However I am unable to login thru the management plugin. Any pointers in this regard will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had updated the hostname of the system and that was causing the issue. See the link below

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rabbitmq-users/9P-BAwGVHJU/fwOpZPJywwYJ

I added 127.0.0.1 'hostname' in /etc/hosts. That solved the management plugin problem. However rabbitmqctl still showed the following error. Restarted rabbitmq and it solved the rabbitmqctl problem as well

```
Listing queues ...
Error: unable to connect to node 'rabbit@<hostname>': nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: ['rabbit@<hostname>']

rabbit@<hostname>:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on <hostname>
  * epmd reports node 'rabbit' running on port 25672
  * TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed
  * suggestion: hostname mismatch?
  * suggestion: is the cookie set correctly?

current node details:
- node name: <nodename>
- home dir: <homedir>
- cookie hash: <cookiehash>
```